# Django and Bootstrap columns

Tags: css, django, bootstrap-4, django-templates

I want to create a row with 3 columns using Bootstrap and Django dynamic content that I want to get in those columns. However, with the code below, my content goes one below the other for some reason. Any help is appreciated.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-sm-12">
                {% for post in object_list %}
                    {% if post.is_on_home_page is True %}
                        <a href="{% url 'categories' post.category.slug %}">
                             {{ post.category }}
                        </a>
                         {% if post.home_or_category_image %}
                            <img class="img-fluid" src="{{ post.home_or_category_image.url }}">
                        {% endif %}
                             {{ post.author }}
                            <a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.slug %}">
                            {{ post.title }}
                            </a>
                            {{ post.snippet }}
                        {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: You mentioned "my content goes one below the other", Can you elaborate or can share frontend screenshot. And what tyou want to achieve ? it's unclear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing something minor wrong in your code. You will have to create a col-lg-4 div grid in each loop iteration.
So place your column div logic inside for loop and the rest will be handled by Django itself.